# MultiDPIBitmapSource in BitmapFill doesn't work

Tags: flash-builder

`MultiDPIBitmapSource` in `BitmapFill` doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
`
<s:Rect id="background2"  left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" percentWidth="100" percentHeight="100"  radiusX="20" >
<s:fill >
<s:BitmapFill id="bgFill" fillMode="repeat">
<s:source>
<s:MultiDPIBitmapSource source160dpi="@Embed('images/backgroundSki/240/abiSefid.jpg')"
                        source240dpi="@Embed('images/backgroundSkin/240/abiSefid.jpg')"
                        source320dpi="@Embed('images/backgroundSkin/320/abiSefid.jpg')"  />
</s:source>
</s:BitmapFill>
</s:fill>
</s:Rect>`
```

Answer (score 0):

work with flash builder some times become so much complicated than another sdk's like visual stadio... we should take care about detail for example in MultiDPIBitmapSource help of flash builder say's:

This class provides a list of bitmaps for various runtime densities.

> `It is supplied as the source to BitmapImage or Image and as the icon
>   of a Button`
>   . The components will use the Application.runtimeDPI to choose which image to display.

so we cant use MultiDPIBitmapSource in bitmapFill in rect . also we maybe want use this code for solve problem:

```
   <fx:Script>
   <![CDATA[
    .
    .
    switch( FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.runtimeDPI)
  {
  case  DPIClassification.DPI_240 :
    bgFill.source =  "images/backgroundSkin/160/image.jpg 
    break;

  case  DPIClassification.DPI_160 :
    bgFill.source =  "images/backgroundSkin/160/image.jpg 
    break;

  case  DPIClassification.DPI_320 :
    bgFill.source =  "images/backgroundSkin/160/image.jpg 
    break;
   }
     .
     .
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    .
    .
<s:Rect id="background2"  left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" width="100%" height="100%" >
        <s:fill>
            <s:BitmapFill  id="bgFill" fillMode="repeat"   />
        </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```

but you can see this code also dont work i think the id of BitmapFill  is anknown in script code .. any way the only way that worked for me was using of loader :
.
.

```
.switch( FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.runtimeDPI)
     {
       case  DPIClassification.DPI_240 :
        loader.load(new URLRequest("images/backgroundSkin/240/image.jpg"));
     loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loaderComplete);
        break;

    case  DPIClassification.DPI_160 :
       loader.load(new URLRequest("images/backgroundSkin/160/image.jpg"));
       loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loaderComplete);
        break;

    case  DPIClassification.DPI_320 :
       loader.load(new URLRequest("images/backgroundSkin/320/image.jpg"));
       loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loaderComplete);
       break;
    }



    }
    public function loaderCompleteHandler(evt:Event):void
    {
        bgFill.source = evt.target.content;
    }
```